# Llenar combobox con base de datos, pero iniciar con blanco

Tags: c#, sql-server, windows-forms

Tengo un combobox que lleno con esta consulta a base de datos:

```
select ' ' as usr_entrada, null as no_servicio union select usr_entrada,  No_Servicio from Telemarketing where Id_Sucursal='cordoba'
```

La idea de la unión es agregar a la selección una fila en blanco, para que aparezca en el combobox y se pueda seleccionar. El caso es que la consulta arroja correctamente los resultados, de esta forma:

```
+--------------+-------------+
| usr_entrada  | no_servicio |
+--------------+-------------+
|              | NULL        |
+--------------+-------------+
| CAPTURA-TMK  | No_Servicio |
+--------------+-------------+
| SUP          | No_Servicio |
+--------------+-------------+
| TCA02TMK     | No_Servicio |
+--------------+-------------+
| TCACONTABAUX | No_Servicio |
+--------------+-------------+
| TMKCBA01     | No_Servicio |
+--------------+-------------+`
```

Pero al llenar el combobox, se "desaparece" la primer línea. El combobox lo lleno de esta forma:

```
void llenaUsuarios()
{
     Conexion con = new Conexion();
     DataTable dt=new DataTable();
     using (con.getcon())
     {
          const string sql = "select ' ' as usr_entrada, null as no_servicio union select usr_entrada,  No_Servicio from Telemarketing where Id_Sucursal=@Sucursal";
          using(SqlCommand cmd=new SqlCommand(sql, con.getcon()))
          {
               SqlDataReader rd;
               cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Sucursal", cveSucursal);
               rd = cmd.ExecuteReader();
               if (rd.HasRows)
               {
                   rd.Read();
                   dt.Load(rd);
                   comboBox1.DisplayMember = "usr_entrada";
                   comboBox1.ValueMember = "no_servicio";
                   comboBox1.DataSource = dt;
               }
          }
     }
}
```

Alguien podría explicarme por qué pasa esto? Tengro otro combobox que se llena de igual manera (aunque otra consulta), y ese no me borra nada.

Agradezco de antemano su apoyo.

Comment: te recomiento mostrar por pantalla la consulta sql y verificar si esta consulta al hacerla directamente sobre sql te arroja resultados.

Comment: esto seria un debug manual ya que tal vez te este omitiendo errores.

Comment: Por cierto, la consulta que haces al principio y la que hay en tu código no son la misma...

Comment: Francisco, como comenté la consulta en sql funciona correctamente y arroja todos los resultados deseados, el resultado es la tabla descrita. El problema es que el combobox "borra" el primer resultado. Ya corregí la consulta Pikoh, la había modificado pensando que ese sería el problema...

Comment: Tal ves esto te sirva, puedes llenarlo con datos como ya lo haces, posteriormente inicializarlo con  comboBox1.ListIndex = -1;

Comment: El combobox no tiene `ListIndex`, creo que eso es de una lista. Probé con comboBox1.Index y, efectivamente, se selecciona en blanco, pero si selecciono un item ya no puedo volver a seleccionar el blanco. El combobox me sirve para seleccionar un filtro, en caso que el usuario lo requiera, o listar todos los registros, por eso el blanco. Gracias por tu comentario!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aunque no es la respuesta que esperaba, encontré una solución: agregar la fila en blanco directo al `datatable` con este código:

```
DataRow r = dt.NewRow();
r[0] = "";
r[1] = null;
dt.Rows.InsertAt(r, 0);
```

Este código lo puse después de asignar el datatable como datasource del combobox.
Ojalá a alguien le sirva en un futuro.

Answer (score 2):

```
 public void llenardatos()
   {
       DataTable tb = new DataTable();
       cone.Open();
       SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("select distinct(País) from Clientes",cone);
       da.Fill(tb);
       cbopais.DisplayMember = "país";
       cbopais.ValueMember = "país";
       cbopais.DataSource = tb;
   }
```

Comment: Podrías añadir un poco de explicación adicional para que el OP pueda entender lo que estás haciendo :)

Comment: Bienvenida, Alexandra! Ojalá puedas explicar qué hace tu código, y cómo responde a mi pregunta. Saludos!

Answer (score 0):

Desafortunadamente el combo box no soporta valores nulos, revisa este link :

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.combobox.objectcollection.add.aspx

Sin  embargo puedes adicionar un ítem sin valor al combo box así:

```
comboBox.Items.Insert(0, string.Empty);
```

Comment: Tienes razon en que el combobox no acepta items nulos, pero este no es el caso. El primer item (si la consulta es correcta) es un `DataRow` con dos columnas, una vacia y otra a `null`.con lo que debería funcionar.

Comment: Se puede agregar un item así como mencionas, cuando el combobox lo estás llenando con `datasource`?